# Two identical subsequences

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to find an effective algorithm (a function) that takes an array of integers A[1..2N] and returns true if the sequence represented in A can be divided into two identical subsequences of length N - and false otherwise.

I don't really know where to start. I was thinking of recursion - such sequences have to begin with A[1] and end with A[2N], but the next step isn't so obvious.

I would appreciate some help

Comment: Do you mean is A[0->N] = A[N->2N], or I can arrange the array in any order and check if it can be divided into two identical sub sequences?

Comment: Well, to be precise: the function is supposed to return true if there exist two sequences i1, ... iN, j1,..., jN, such that

1 <= i1 < i2 < ... < iN <=2N
   
1 <= j1 < j2 < ... < jN <=2N
      and 
ik != jk  and A[ik]=A[jk] for all k=1,2,...,N

Comment: Well, I thought of one and posted it below. Maybe you can share one new?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-hard-is-unshuffling-a-string . Unless we exclude inputs with six or more copies of one integer, this is an NP-hard problem.

Answer (score 1):

Function CHECK() will do your duty if you are really expecting this..

Hope it will help

```
int A[]={1,2,1,3,4,2,3,4};
int vis[10];

bool CHECK()
{
    vis[10]={0};
    int j=1;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(vis[i]==1) continue;
        bool find = false;

        for(; j<10; j++)
        {
            if(A[i]==A[j])
            {
                find=true;
                vis[i]=1;
                vis[j]=1;
                j++;
                break;
            }
        }
       if(!find)
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, though I was trying to think of a linearly-complex algorithm

Comment: You are looking for O(n) algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I think it's possible. I think I have an idea, I'll try to upload it in a while

Comment: If it is possible, update me.. I think It is not possible as you have to compare and maintain sequence

Comment: Breaks on inputs like 1,1,2,1,1,2.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not the perfect code yet, but the idea is this pseudo-code

```
function sameSubsequences(A:array[1..2n] of integer):boolean;

begin
memory:array[1..2n] of boolean; 
for i:=1 to 2n do memory[i]:=false;
i:=1; j:=2;
while i<=2n AND j<=2n do
    begin
    memory[i]:=true;
    while j<=2n and A[j]!=A[i] and (not memory[j]) do j:=j+1;
    if j<=2n then memory[j]:=true;
    while i<=2n or memory[i] do i:=i+1;
    end;

sameSubsequences:=(i>2n);
end;
```

Comment: This is not O(n) .. You have nested while loop.. You have one more extra inner loop than the code I provide..

Comment: I doesn't mean it's not linear.

Comment: Breaks on inputs like 1,1,2,1,1,2.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat you are right, that disqualifies my approach to the problem. Maybe you could give me some hint on where to begin?